# Paypal account upgrade to express from standard

Tags: paypal

We are currently using PayPal standard checkout and we need to upgrade to express checkout.

From PayPal documentation, standard checkout will reach their site and each checkout process will be handled by PayPal and return confirmation alone to our site.
But express checkout is different in workflow that everything need to be done with API and script.

How to upgrade easily from standard checkout ?
Or write up the API only be the solution to upgrade.

We are looking for .Net library based integration process. Any NuGet package available for this integration.

Answer (score 0):

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls); there is a [Checkout-NET-SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalCheckoutSdk/) you can use. These two routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair your two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Hi, Actually i am using checkout.js now and using payment method created order and i am struct with getting approval now. order creation succeeded. how to proceed with showing order details and get approval ? and when will onAuthorize method will call

Comment: checkout.js is deprecated, so best to switch to the above with onApprove. See that code sample.

Comment: Express checkout will not support tax auto calculation also based on some state  ? in standard checkout once customer provided address tax will be auto calculated in PayPal itself.

Comment: When integrating with an API, you do all calculations yourself.