# Paypal v2 express checkout integration in .NET

Tags: paypal

I am currently checking integration process of v2 express checkout and lot of documentation making confusion.

So far i am using checkout.js from paypal domain and using below code for order creation in client side as below

paypal.Button.render({
env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

```
        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        style: {
            color: 'gold',
            shape: 'rect',
            label: 'paypal',
            size: 'medium',
            tagline: false,
            width: 150
        },

        payment: function (data, actions) {
            /* Set up a url on your server to create the payment */
            var CREATE_URL = '/paypal/createpaypalPayment';

            /* Make a call to your server to set up the payment */
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_URL)
                .then(function ({ result }) {
                    var test = JSON.parse(result);
                    return test.id;
                });
            
        },

        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
            /* Set up a url on your server to execute the payment */
            var EXECUTE_URL = '/paypal/executepaypalPayment';

            /* Set up the data you need to pass to your server */
            var data = {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID: data.payerID
            };
            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_URL, data)
                .then(function (res) {
                    return null;
                });
        
        }

        
    }, '#paypalcheckout');
});
```

Please find the server side code for create order.

```
    [HttpPost]
         public JsonResult createpaypalpayment()
         {
            var client = new WebClient();
            string credentials = clientid + secretid;
            client.Headers.Add("authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
            client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en_US");
            client.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");

            var body = @"{
                  ""intent"": ""AUTHORIZE"",
                  ""purchase_units"": [{
                  ""amount"": {
                    ""currency_code"": ""USD"",
                    ""value"": ""100.00""
                }
            }]
                }";

            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                var response = client.UploadString("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/", "POST", body);
                return Json(new { result = response }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                
}
            }
}
```

I referred below documentation
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/orders-integration-guide/#integration-steps

I am struct with how to show order details after order creation and get approval from customer end ?
Can anyone provide suggestion for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

checkout.js is deprecated and that documentation is archived, so my suggestion is that you follow the current documentation on developer.paypal.com

In [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67314956/paypal-account-upgrade-to-express-from-standard), links were provided to that documentation.